# Passing g++ compiler flags stored in a variable not working as expected

Tags: shell, terminal

So I have a file example.cpp which I have to compile with g++.

```
$ g++ nginx.cpp libuaparser_cpp.a -I ~/Desktop/boost_1_68_0/  -I /usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.12/include/jdbc/ -L /usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.12/lib64/  -L ~/Desktop/boost_1_68_0/stage/lib   -L /usr/local/lib/  -L /Users/Shray/Desktop/boost_1_68_0/stage/lib/ ~/Desktop/boost_1_68_0/stage/lib/libboost_regex.a  -lyaml-cpp -lboost_regex -std=c++11  -lmysqlcppconn
```

So instead of writing so much, I put the rest of the parameters in a variable in my terminal.

```
$ myvar="libuaparser_cpp.a -I ~/Desktop/boost_1_68_0/  -I /usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.12/include/jdbc/ -L /usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.12/lib64/  -L ~/Desktop/boost_1_68_0/stage/lib   -L /usr/local/lib/  -L /Users/Shray/Desktop/boost_1_68_0/stage/lib/ ~/Desktop/boost_1_68_0/stage/lib/libboost_regex.a  -lyaml-cpp -lboost_regex -std=c++11  -lmysqlcppconn"

$ g++ nginx.cpp $myvar
```

But this gives me an error.

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '~/Desktop/boost_1_68_0/stage/lib/libboost_regex.a'
```

Why is this error coming? Since I am just adding the variables value. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use variables to store a content that is a list, use arrays! Also `~` doesn't expand under quotes (single or double)

```
myVarArgs=()
myVarArgs=( libuaparser_cpp.a 
           -I ~/Desktop/boost_1_68_0/
           -I /usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.12/include/jdbc/
           -L /usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.12/lib64/
           -L ~/Desktop/boost_1_68_0/stage/lib
           -L /usr/local/lib/
           -L /Users/Shray/Desktop/boost_1_68_0/stage/lib/
           ~/Desktop/boost_1_68_0/stage/lib/libboost_regex.a  
           -lyaml-cpp 
           -lboost_regex 
           -std=c++11  
           -lmysqlcppconn
          )
```

and run a full-quoted expansion to preserve the args from breaking up on presence of special characters.

```
g++ nginx.cpp "${myVarArgs[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Tilde expansion happens before variable expansion, so `~` in a variable isn't expanded to your home directory by the shell. Use the full path.